# php query equal chart

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I use of codeigniter(php) and have a table in database i want select query equal words no whatever it looks like it is.

For example I have the following table in the database MySQL:

I want get row that have num `2` of Active column.what do i do?

```
+----------------------------------------+
|     Name      Active       Insert_Time |
+----------------------------------------+
|     mon         2222       1481203712  |
|     tue         2          1481202788  |
|     wed         222        1481202581  |
|     thu         22         1479902588  |
+----------------------------------------+
```

I've tried like this:

```
$search_term = $this->input->post('search');
$this->db->select('Active, Name', FALSE);
$this->db->where('Active LIKE', '%'.$search_term_num.'%');
$query = $this->db->get('submit_house');
```

this query give me all rows, but I'd just row 2

Comment: Why can't you just say `Active = 2`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$this->db->get_where()`:

```
$query = $this->db->get_where('database_table', array('Active' => 2));
```

Source:
https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html